# How to forbid particular windows update?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation, updates

I have original Windows 7 Ultimate but a month before I have started to see the following message on every PC turn on:

> On this computer not original copy of windows is installed

After some reading I have found the following [discussion](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/w7itproperf/thread/b00d9212-65d9-4f00-89cf-1421197720f1) telling that this issue is caused by particular windows update:

> So far it seems that uninstalling kb971033 solved the problem of the
>   warning window popping up. It was becoming quite a nuisance.

I have uninstalled the update and the pop up stop to come up. Now, a week after, the update is installed again and I get the same message. Some people told me to disable my updates but why I should do this, after I have bought my windows and want support?

So, my questions is is there a way to forbid only this update of being installed?

Comment: Did you install the same windows key on multiple computers? Also did you run [MGADiag.exe](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012) and post it to the [Windows 7 Genuine Advantage Validation Issues (Windows 7)](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/genuinewindows7/threads) forum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the Install type to "Notify Before Download" and when you see the update, make a right click on it and select "Hide update". Now Windows ignores the update.

Comment: This should be a last resort, after all attempts to solve the activation problem have failed.